# Advantage of using CustomAttributes vs GetCustomAttributes()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

I noticed today that some new properties had appeared in my intellisense on the `System.Type` object for my .NET 4.5 projects. Among these was one called `CustomAttributes`.

I was intrigued by this since I previously had understood that `GetCustomAttributes` was one of the most expensive reflection calls (`DynamicInvoke` and the like aside, of course). As I understand it, every call to `GetCustomAttributes` results in calling the constructors for the attributes (and thus a memory allocation). I've often resorted to caching the custom attributes separately to avoid performance bottlenecks when processing large numbers of types and such.

So, I wrote up a test to see if `CustomAttributes` was any more performant than `GetCustomAttributes`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Attributed).GetType());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        var attrs = typeof(Attributed)
            .CustomAttributes
            .Select(a => a.AttributeType)
            .ToList();
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Using .NET 4.5 CustomAttributes property: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        var attrs = typeof(Attributed)
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Select(a => a.GetType())
            .ToList();
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Using GetCustomAttributes method: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
}
```

With some test classes:

```
[Dummy]
[Dummy]
[Dummy]
[Dummy]
[Dummy]
[Dummy]
class Attributed
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=true)]
class DummyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DummyAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

The results were surprising:

```
System.RuntimeType
Using .NET 4.5 CustomAttributes property: 00:00:00.1351259
Using GetCustomAttributes method: 00:00:00.0803161
```

The new `CustomAttributes` property was actually slower than the existing `GetCustomAttributes` method!

Debugging further, I discovered that the attribute constructors were not called for iterating `CustomAttributes` (which I expected since it looks like it is just reading the metadata). Yet somehow, it was slower than `GetCustomAttributes` which calls constructors.

### My Question

Personally I think it is more readable to use the new property, but the cost is 1.5x-ish slower performance.

So, what advantage is there, if any, of using `CustomAttributes` instead of `GetCustomAttributes()`?

I'm assuming the situation where we are simply checking to see if an attribute of some type exists on the clas...not using methods or properties on the instance of the attribute.

Comment: That's a tiny difference considering the simplicity of the benchmark. This can probably just be discarded as within the margin of error. Have you compared the actual implementation of these APIs?

Comment: Yes it is a pretty smal difference, but it does scale and maintain that 1.5x ratio when increasing the number of iterations which means that it could make an impact when iterating a very large number of things with custom attributes. I'm attempting to find an assembly to point ILSpy at to take a look at the implementation (unless I can find it on the reference source thing they have online first)

Comment: I'm more interested in why it's slower, honestly. I would have expected it to be significantly faster since it's just reading out the metadata for the type which `GetCustomAttributes` would need to do anyway. Perhaps the process of getting the `ConstructorInfo` and other things is more expensive than I'm thinking?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are making a traditional benchmarking mistake, one that makes many .NET programmers think that Reflection is slow.  Slower than it actually is.  Reflection is very lazy, you don't pay for it when you don't use it.  Which makes your *first* measurement include all the cost of page-faulting the metadata into RAM and setup the type info reflection cache.  That cost is not included in the second measurement, making GetCustomAttributes() look better than it actually is.

Always include a loop around the benchmark code, run it 10 times.  You'll now see that the CustomAttributes property isn't actually *that* slow, I measure it at (roughly) 0.083 vs 0.063 seconds, ~30% slower.

The CustomAttributes property needed to be added in .NET 4.5 to support the language projection for WinRT.  You cannot use GetCustomAttributes() in a Store, Phone or PCL project.  Reflection is *very* different in WinRT, an inevitable side-effect of it being a COM based api.  Implementation code is enough to make anyone's eyes bleed but the broad outline is that the property is implemented in C# and the method is implemented in the CLR.  The C# code needs to do more work to handle the language projection details so is inevitably slower.

So just keep using GetCustomAttributes(), use the property when you have to.  A 30% speed difference isn't otherwise a drastic reason to compromise style and readability, apply your common sense.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted by answers by sjb-sjb and JL0PD, the two things do not give the same information, so they are meaningless to compare.

I recommend a third way, under .NET 4.5 and later, namely the new extension methods. For example:

```
typeof(Attributed).GetCustomAttributes()                  // no bool 'inherit' on this overload
```

or:

```
typeof(Attributed).GetCustomAttributes<DummyAttribute>()  // gets only attributes of the specified type, and no need for casting
```

To have these extensions methods in scope, you need directive:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions).

Answer (score 1):

An important difference seems to be that CustomAttributes returns IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> while GetCustomAttributes returns object[] containing instances derived from Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As of net6, `GetCustomAttributes` surprisingly checks for accessibility of attribute relative to type it's applied while `CustomAttributes` don't. This can be observed when you generate assemblies at runtime and apply own internal attributes to generated type. Consider following assemblies in program

```
program
| -- DefaultAssembly # assembly generated by C# compiler, loaded from dll on disk
|       MyInternalAttribute # type is declared in code and compiled to currently executing program
| -- ReflectionEmitDynamicAssembly # assembly created at runtime with AssemblyBuilder
|       RuntimeGeneratedType # type is generated at runtime and annotated with MyInternalAttribute
```

Given variable `type` of type `System.Type` pointing to `RuntimeGeneratedType` and accessing `type.GetCustomAttributes().Count()` will give you `0`, but accessing `type.CustomAttributes.Count()` will give you `1`. This can be avoided by using commonly known `InternalsVisibleTo`, but you'll need to mark your assemblies. Alternatively `IgnoresAccessChecksTo` can be used to annotate generated assembly.